# Clustering with CLARA in R: Mysterious dataset causes problems. Why?

Tags: r, debugging, cluster-analysis

I have discovered a dataset that causes `R`'s CLARA algorithm to fail (i.e. enter an apparently infinite loop). Why does it fail?

What I find strange is that the dataset is extremely boring (basically just a normal variable with a dummy-coded categorical variable), but also because changing nearly ANYTHING about the dataset or the call to `cluster::clara` avoids the problem.

Anyone have insight here? I apologize for not including the random seed and program I used to generate this dataset; unfortunately, the code that generated this is a rather large set of programs drawing from parallel random number generators (generated using the `rlecuyer` package). I haven't been able to replicate the generation process on a standard PC, so here is the raw dataset below. The bug does appear to replicate across operating systems and versions of `R`. An example `sessionInfo()` is shown below.

One possible clue is that the algorithm seemed slightly more likely to fail when there was no true group structure in the continuous random variable (first column). Even so, I had to go through thousands of iterations before finding a dataset that failed.

---

```
# self contained example
library(cluster)
strangeData <- c(-0.866285627488327,1,0,0
,-0.510951849076121,0,0,1
,-1.17167514108559,0,1,0
,-0.376762528272389,1,0,0
,0.78146409125879,0,1,0
,1.61782054548358,0,0,1
,1.13870520606875,1,0,0
,-1.13486644861899,0,0,1
,-0.206927567036607,0,0,0
,-0.207869481212349,0,0,1
,-0.744628008025243,0,1,0
,0.731433838031448,0,0,1
,1.62303204478421,0,1,0
,0.336307634488861,1,0,0
,1.81605021862297,1,0,0
,-0.750411588420933,1,0,0
,-0.0238025825151884,0,1,0
,-1.15317047678752,0,0,1
,-1.16535479706466,0,1,0
,-0.902957290471365,0,1,0
,0.757365905566296,0,0,0
,0.327956357831982,1,0,0
,-1.21209036793528,1,0,0
,-0.827813655803123,0,0,1
,1.29462065083151,1,0,0
,-1.18875004333554,0,0,1
,0.30436829237833,1,0,0
,0.686761122942272,0,0,1
,0.348318524543705,0,0,0
,0.00772114748248065,0,1,0
,-0.0654531320746511,0,1,0
,-0.871825468631758,1,0,0
,-0.24260740899128,1,0,0
,1.6316283625827,0,0,0
,-0.157380038359798,1,0,0
,-1.13594228151195,0,0,1
,0.397846678544776,0,0,0
,-1.79295787039272,0,1,0
,0.659894781274625,0,0,0
,-0.170073590508157,0,0,0
,-0.813943074670405,0,0,0
,-0.382343008302335,0,1,0
,1.00965255945214,1,0,0
,-0.325407591983216,0,0,0
,-0.192348595055317,0,1,0
,-0.776963720822561,0,0,1
,0.412818265336597,0,0,0
,-0.372215722029941,0,1,0
,-0.626596060936548,1,0,0
,1.77998358890641,0,0,1
,1.28471804407001,1,0,0
,2.30521501151449,0,0,1
,-0.0434857353479769,0,1,0
,0.129337095832911,0,0,0
,0.490060486314237,0,0,0
,0.0219239584969476,0,1,0
,2.16246213170809,1,0,0
,-1.6463259663705,0,1,0
,-1.25945578842163,0,1,0
,-0.0508902150466008,1,0,0
,-0.761232947984076,0,0,1
,-1.0844017226841,1,0,0
,0.768163697492781,1,0,0
,0.0512967198361093,0,0,0
,0.496505407614941,0,1,0
,-0.875095658442669,0,0,0
,0.356165420230564,0,1,0
,-1.48736915282316,0,0,0
,0.605835916959207,1,0,0
,0.150248856364222,0,0,1
,0.436072890825432,0,0,0
,-1.2477307042077,0,1,0
,-0.925825618397317,0,0,1
,-0.865719152703743,0,0,0
,1.49904943876406,0,0,0
,-2.000710979317,0,0,0
,-0.592352714624327,0,0,0
,0.393289445874399,0,1,0
,-0.394123590756249,1,0,0
,-0.352673107317825,0,0,1
,0.695357507195699,0,0,1
,-0.0040347449129765,0,1,0
,-0.127791150003591,0,0,1
,0.474647838412314,1,0,0
,0.621985643440749,0,1,0
,-0.0963944386034655,0,0,0
,-0.0769711593827088,0,0,1
,1.52062637216907,0,1,0
,-0.0171131048538696,0,0,1
,-0.614781568866571,0,0,1
,-0.428078937440796,0,0,1
,1.46996872384325,0,0,1
,1.33611500009041,0,1,0
,0.0849546480618341,1,0,0
,1.16189138672992,0,1,0
,-0.0892214257894575,0,0,1
,0.639365524696794,0,0,1
,0.601135082783273,1,0,0
,0.507344807255368,1,0,0
,-0.933432615481704,0,1,0
,1.0605270726388,1,0,0
,-0.846884297959019,0,1,0
,0.069757909351883,0,0,0
,0.971079516592758,0,0,1
,2.13895542286282,0,1,0
,-1.07521573310271,0,0,0
,-0.578762770935955,0,0,1
,0.138245534658141,0,1,0
,0.472499258515774,0,1,0
,-0.955048693548485,0,1,0
,-0.541270774805467,0,0,0
,-0.965725893217509,0,1,0
,1.23937418822633,0,0,0
,0.572605101793754,0,0,1
,1.25059599135706,0,0,0
,0.224476582002008,0,1,0
,-0.0466083676818374,1,0,0
,1.58857119911245,0,0,1
,-1.85121285531852,1,0,0
,0.506446004536966,0,0,0
,0.00529547247104709,0,1,0
,-0.67761610257275,0,1,0
,-0.050520398113479,1,0,0
,1.09977836234059,0,0,0
,-0.729074108182476,0,0,0
,-0.0290602916500079,0,0,0
,0.610785941871284,1,0,0
,0.224899327520079,1,0,0
,1.01797352389614,0,0,0
,0.258960174013477,1,0,0
,-0.0173109255243736,1,0,0
,1.15675575673647,0,0,0
,-1.40075651100777,0,1,0
,1.29973838021484,0,0,0
,-2.19964416776033,0,1,0
,1.43949364450352,0,0,1
,1.07342747391928,0,0,1
,-1.20048803661996,0,0,0
,-0.346455976764648,0,0,0
,-0.480774942257163,0,1,0
,-0.743609323884268,0,1,0
,1.54622738113784,0,1,0
,-0.403898403935946,0,0,0
,-0.833433145942438,1,0,0
,-0.219164470718774,1,0,0
,0.12696814119287,1,0,0
,-0.322315905835392,0,0,0
,-0.350597318362615,1,0,0
,-0.657947808709103,0,0,1
,-1.3599769112632,0,1,0
,-0.101630823838928,0,0,0
,-1.34660046284197,1,0,0
,-2.42751597395552,0,1,0
,-0.890211205480196,1,0,0
,-1.24558895213474,0,0,1
,0.18700333641652,1,0,0
,2.5082251629743,1,0,0
,1.33292648093108,1,0,0
,-0.38816796929655,0,0,1
,-0.340299350153559,0,0,1
,-0.360408688017778,0,0,1
,0.184527132500589,0,0,1
,-0.945284123204619,0,0,0
,-0.447915791428278,0,0,0
,0.960837246768647,0,1,0
,0.261390181284487,0,0,1
,1.99391928572872,1,0,0
,1.63328530659267,0,1,0
,0.841678645192176,0,1,0
,0.807348533253569,0,1,0
,-1.69473655701435,0,0,0
,-2.95460714558617,1,0,0
,-1.64969453370585,0,0,1
,-0.484414672869815,0,1,0
,-0.526272870810604,0,0,0
,0.051830062343814,0,0,1
,1.26507516617792,1,0,0
,-1.41617967114385,0,0,0
,0.236754759425436,0,0,0
,0.904212403266786,0,0,1
,2.42448681816761,0,0,1
,-1.57101731154911,1,0,0
,-0.471525015273919,0,0,1
,-0.777691881154585,0,0,0
,-0.33500864971305,1,0,0
,-0.804758127002811,1,0,0
,1.31836909690498,0,0,1
,0.0609487604963864,0,0,0
,-0.443936034513707,0,0,0
,0.740834846236723,0,0,1
,-2.14041576208016,0,0,0
,-0.650625084741614,0,0,1
,-0.314809179050786,0,0,0
,0.623191053756259,0,0,0
,-0.861527811786575,0,0,0
,-0.495712634432739,0,0,0
,-1.15138427720019,0,0,0
,-0.0368657006311513,0,0,1
,0.808099625439217,0,1,0
,2.04358789173449,0,1,0
,-0.361230312246911,0,1,0
,-1.43757174215673,0,0,1
,-0.0126368333853388,0,0,1
,-0.55062321407905,0,0,1
,-0.598669467196556,0,0,0
,0.553538760296604,0,1,0
,0.0331404550587805,0,1,0
,-1.01641207011743,0,0,0
,-0.969763233966749,1,0,0
,-0.115985687817581,0,0,0
,-1.44923317467671,0,1,0
,0.58359088336307,0,0,1
,1.02177931523912,0,0,0
,-0.772903258762401,0,1,0
,-0.833203951806085,1,0,0
,-0.121756851474623,0,0,1
,0.333735580183243,0,0,0
,0.841447311750965,0,0,1
,-0.202542681685737,1,0,0
,-0.363835977102042,0,0,1
,-0.763208653073085,0,0,0
,-0.404233770949925,0,0,0
,-0.626967850505697,0,0,1
,1.51902583641424,0,0,1
,0.152334670353581,1,0,0
,-0.37793809368425,0,1,0
,0.958745025661511,1,0,0
,-1.44235110382376,0,1,0
,0.0234173973335753,0,0,1
,0.381965794662393,0,0,0
,-0.987421186811441,1,0,0
,0.680391323949574,1,0,0
,-0.200195019135693,1,0,0
,-1.11687467522201,0,0,1
,0.484415933230296,0,0,0
,0.66465930418491,1,0,0
,0.135520835347015,0,0,0
,-0.0135948380436641,0,0,0
,-0.174610953673981,1,0,0
,-0.385258324842704,0,0,1
,0.0736764406605341,0,1,0
,0.433497723474607,0,0,1
,-1.57962309060262,0,0,1
,0.630090656840841,1,0,0
,0.973500666410068,0,1,0
,-0.509883991863271,0,1,0
,0.776678864294335,1,0,0
,1.06439033722933,0,0,1
,0.631572825803999,0,0,1
,0.736226086691134,0,0,0
,-1.23321773011943,1,0,0
,-0.388575379622945,0,1,0
,1.0632151634506,0,0,1
,1.05814098386583,0,0,0
,0.408184424450004,0,0,1
,0.531436889048738,1,0,0
,2.20381966762526,0,0,1
,2.11422588577572,0,0,1
,-0.531704962557588,0,0,0
,1.34561800389927,0,0,1
,0.273769623933743,1,0,0
,-0.372910934670834,0,0,1
,-0.470566520010902,1,0,0
,-0.75477217389578,0,1,0
,-0.501842228377673,0,0,1
,-1.25532930322808,0,0,0
,-0.286477761094775,1,0,0
,-0.823694457831787,0,0,1
,0.797314566796799,0,0,1
,-0.0600523761224243,0,1,0
,0.657605378335186,0,0,0
,-0.725821254759635,0,1,0
,-1.1218762657447,0,1,0
,1.02390098776472,1,0,0
,-0.125900354616813,0,1,0
,-0.110600677983877,0,0,1
,0.362848077657443,0,1,0
,1.75245676080733,0,0,1
,-1.53945786644643,0,0,0
,-1.69041842719508,1,0,0
,2.21366606351434,0,1,0
,1.59672297659057,0,0,1
,1.36855862766991,0,0,0
,-0.59109080681349,1,0,0
,0.344628944020705,0,0,0
,-0.547730633367544,1,0,0
,3.28229260418702,0,1,0
,0.186377905391717,0,0,1
,-0.85647024545773,0,0,0
,-2.10613283819929,1,0,0
,1.0659329233981,1,0,0
,0.197594622321815,0,0,0
,-1.5165240972921,0,0,1
,-1.10653359569001,0,0,0
,-0.702450947236347,0,1,0
,0.561612881169714,0,1,0
,0.0618497778342936,0,1,0
,-1.61352989112514,0,0,1
,-0.380008609813976,0,1,0
,0.485668785864403,1,0,0
,1.44073309607887,0,0,0
,-0.631502388683978,0,1,0
,0.924636979461146,0,1,0
,-0.385053889933482,1,0,0
,1.7335479754834,1,0,0
,0.804525293681982,0,0,1
,-0.991585017557505,0,1,0
,1.35969572742296,0,1,0
,0.76841232389423,0,1,0
,-0.133117031661697,1,0,0
,-1.57093944605932,1,0,0
,0.0463315954106568,1,0,0
,0.0400112040904778,0,1,0
,0.542965613556832,0,0,1
,-0.951132065936325,0,1,0
,1.0236860490532,1,0,0
,-1.65166967479243,1,0,0
,-0.31690124841045,1,0,0
,-0.236230990447918,1,0,0
,2.15914099741492,1,0,0
,1.31763979031855,0,0,1
,-0.607279994041944,0,0,1
,1.13453737158436,0,0,1
,0.6701910306058,0,1,0
,-0.564864937395887,1,0,0
,0.926205103954728,1,0,0
,-0.980200111995638,0,1,0
,0.437252455381278,0,1,0
,-1.13416837126914,0,1,0
,0.780011292450117,0,0,0
,0.558179248192722,0,0,1
,-0.788560632585296,0,0,1
,1.42188103521719,1,0,0
,-1.25403745185199,0,1,0
,-0.961543192416867,0,0,1
,0.272005872845942,0,0,0
,-0.3754160451173,1,0,0
,-1.40457905909558,0,0,0
,0.0564752608649083,0,1,0
,0.0717952713169958,1,0,0
,1.27361011457374,0,1,0
,-1.13881319792865,0,0,1
,-1.43642545765708,0,0,0
,1.56419289350468,0,0,0
,-0.539863901494306,1,0,0
,-0.649284486134111,0,0,1
,-0.816485163999317,0,0,0
,-0.586168990002293,0,0,0
,1.33236676326001,0,0,0
,0.897539764461409,1,0,0)
```

Here is the analysis part

```
strangeData <- matrix(strangeData,byrow=T,ncol=4)

# Remove any column (and probably any row) and it works
# Decrease samples below 42 and it works
# Set sampsize to 199 or 201 and it works
# Change distance to euclidean and it works
# set pamLike to F and it works
resClaraManDum <- clara(    
  x=strangeData
 ,k=2
 ,metric='manhattan'
 ,samples=42
 ,sampsize=200
 ,pamLike=T
)
```

And relevant information about my system:

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] cluster_1.14.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.2
```

Comment: I suggest you raise this on R Devel or with the maintainer of the **cluster** package directly. But for all our sanity, put the comma at the end of the line not the start of the next; your code is hideous!

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've contacted the maintainer since posting. Regarding commas; I picked up the comma at the start of the line from a former compsci prof of mine -- I hated it too initially, but once you get used to it, the number of misplaced commas in your code dramatically decreases. I highly recommend it!